# Is it possible to have relative paths for content in MVC4 areas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In the razor view I have the following to link to a css file localised to the area:

```
 <link href='@Url.Content("~/areas/adminarea/content/area.css")' rel="stylesheet" />
```

Is there any way that this can be achieved relative to the area if the view is already in the area, instead of a full path to the area?

Index view is rendered by linking to the following controller:

```
http://localhost:54443/adminarea/admin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your own Helper method to transform your area-local path to a global-path at runtime.

Here's a question with a similar approach as a solution:
[Relative Content Path in MVC3 Areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130226/relative-content-path-in-mvc3-areas)